# Can two tables ever get the same OID on pg_class?

Tags: postgresql

On Postgres, I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify a table regardless of name changes.  OIDs seem apt for that.  But OIDs wrap after 2^32-1.

If OIDs were to wrap, can I get two tables with the same OID on pg_class?  Or is there something that would prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oid` column is a primary key of `pg_class`:

```
=> \d pg_class
                     Table "pg_catalog.pg_class"
       Column        |     Type     | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------
 oid                 | oid          |           | not null | 
 relname             | name         |           | not null | 
 relnamespace        | oid          |           | not null | 

(... other columns)

 reloptions          | text[]       | C         |          | 
 relpartbound        | pg_node_tree | C         |          | 
Indexes:
    "pg_class_oid_index" PRIMARY KEY, btree (oid)
    "pg_class_relname_nsp_index" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (relname, relnamespace)
    "pg_class_tblspc_relfilenode_index" btree (reltablespace, relfilenode)
```

So no, two tables can't have the same OID.

When creating a new table, if the OID generator produces a value that conflicts with an existing row, Postgres iterates until it finds an OID that doesn't conflict.

See the code at [`GetNewOidWithIndex`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/catalog/catalog.c;h=c39da41d2ecbc7d2d5c51c998e53de9ec0dc27aa;hb=HEAD#l283) to see the commented implementation.